# How to use state.setError with :records in CMFFormController

Tags: plone, zope

I'm using cmfformcontroller in an app to manage a list of entries.

Entries are displayed using :records as documented at http://pypi.python.org/pypi/zope.httpform

```
<form action=".">
 <p>Please, enter information about one or more of your next of
  kin.</p>

  <p>
    First Name <input type="text" name="people.fname:records" />
    Last Name <input type="text" name="people.lname:records" />
  </p>

  <p>
    First Name <input type="text" name="people.fname:records" />
    Last Name <input type="text" name="people.lname:records" />
  </p>

  <p>
    First Name <input type="text" name="people.fname:records" />
    Last Name <input type="text" name="people.lname:records" />
  </p>

  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

I want my validator to be able to highlight a record using state.setError method. How could I achieve this ?

Comment: Are you required to use CMFFormController? If so, I'd think about how you would do it manually, then read the CMFFormController docs (http://plone.org/documentation/manual/developer-manual/forms/using-cmfformcontroller) to see what it offers to make easier for you (e.g. validation). Otherwise, I probably wouldn't use CMFFormController.

Comment: @aclark yes I'm forced to used this old stuff ... Too much dev has been done on the project  where i'm just an helping resource. /me wanna cry :) I have fix this use case by keeping a list of error key pattern: on starting by a pattern: id_field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fix this use case by keeping a list of error key pattern: on starting by a pattern: id_field